# Read a word and replace ENTIRE LINE of that word with speceifed new string

Tags: vbscript

eg : `code.vbs file1.txt "hello" "hello1"`

This replaces hello with hello1 but not the entire line of hello with hello1.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso,strFilename,strSearch,strReplace,objFile,oldContent,newContent

strFilename = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
strSearch   = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
strReplace  = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)

'Does file exist?
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(strFilename) = False Then
   WScript.Echo "file not found!"
   WScript.Quit
End If

'Read file
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename, 1)
oldContent = objFile.ReadAll

'Write file
newContent = Replace(oldContent, strSearch, strReplace, 1, -1, 0)
Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strFilename, 2)
objFile.Write newContent
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2(v=vs.84).aspx) replacement to match a whole line:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = ".*" & strSearch & ".*(\r?\n)"
re.IgnoreCase = False
re.Global     = True

newContent = re.Replace(oldContent, strReplace & "$1")
```

Comment: `re.Global = True` to replace all Hellos; `strReplace = strReplace & vbCr` to keep a vbCrLf EOL-marker.

Comment: Thanks for ur help but, no changes happen . File remains same as it as.

Comment: @Charmendor Then you made a mistake. Please edit your question and show your updated code.